# Find $\mathrm{Gal}(L, \mathbb{Q})$ and prove that $\sqrt[3]{3} \in L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I am really struggling on these consecutive questions on Galois Theory:

**Question 1:** Suppose $L$ is a normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{5}) $ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Find $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

Would this be the cyclic product $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_3} $ or $\mathbb{Z_6}$?

**Question 2:** Apply Galois theory to prove that $\sqrt[3]{3} \not\in L$.

$\sqrt[3]{3}$ clearly does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$  and cannot be obtained using a composition of typical operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication etc) of $\sqrt[3]{2} $ and $\sqrt[3]{5} $ but how can I show this using Galois theory?

Many thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1 :**

The possible values by an $L$-automorphism for $\sqrt[3]{2}$ are $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $j\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $j^2\sqrt[3]{2}$. And for $\sqrt[3]{5}$ it is $\sqrt[3]{5}$,  $j\sqrt[3]{5}$ and $j^2\sqrt[3]{5}$. But the complex $j$ appears in our expressions, so the closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{5})$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{5},j)$. And the possible images of $j$ by an $L$-automorphism are $j$ and $j^2$. So by considering all the combinations possible, there is a total of 18 possible $L$-automorphisms, and 17 of these automorphisms are of order 3, 17 are of order 6, one is of order 2 and there is $\mathrm{Id}$, so $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic with $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z_3}$.

Comment: I'm assuming $j$ is a primitive cube root of unity? What about the map $j\mapsto j^2$?

Comment: $j^2$ is also a primitive root of the unity. Indeed $(j^2)^2=j$ and $(j^2)^3=1$

Comment: I'm aware of that. My point is you're missing an automorphism.

Comment: I uploaded the table of the automorphisms and I don't think I miss any automorphism. But corect my answer if I am wrong.

Comment: You're missing the map $j\mapsto j^2$. The Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}},5^{\frac{1}{3}})$ is $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}},5^{\frac{1}{3}},j)$, which has degree 18 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Oh alright got it i correct my answer.

Comment: I’m not sure that your description of the Galois group is correct, because a structure of $S_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ would imply that there was a normal and cyclic extension of $\Bbb Q$ in there, and I believe that that’s not so.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is cyclic and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},j)$ is normal. There is only 5 groups of order 18 : $D_{18}$, $Z_{18}$, $S_3\times\Bbb Z_3$, $Z_6\times\Bbb Z_3$ and the eneralized dihedral group for E9. But only $S_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ has this configuration of orders for its elements if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Jennifer hi, thanks for your reply. Could you give me some adivce on how to go about such questions as finding galois groups. Or do I just need to develop an intuition for what they may be isomorphic to? I find Galois theory very hard at the moment

Comment: You have to know the groups of little orders. And then you try to find the orders of the elements in the group of Galois and compare it with the possible groups of the same order as the group of Galois. But I have to recognize that in your case the Galois group was rather big... But you will see that some types of groups happen frequantly : $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p},j)$ will give $\Bbb Z_n$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2},\sqrt[2]{3})$will give $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},j)$ gives $S_3$.